# Storing a cfwindow as a coldfusion module

Tags: coldfusion, module, cfwindow

I'm a coldfusion newbie. I have a cfwindow that performs various tasks for me with a form that rests inside it. All that works well, except now I want to add the cfwindow to many pages, and I'd like to do so with some kind of module that can reside in one spot for easy editing in the future. Does coldfusion have anything like a module? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ColdFusion has lots of things like modules:

- Cfinclude just includes another CF page in the current page
- CustomTags
  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=reuseCode_2.html
  are very powerful
- ColdFusion components can have display as well as business logic in
  them -
  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UseFlexDataService_05.html